# Image upload issue in 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1

[image: Image Upload & Browse Issue]

When i wants upload any image for product, i can't get image Browse and Upload Image option. I am using Magento 1.9.0.1. How can i solve this issue?

Comment: Which browser are you using? have you checked if Adobe flash is installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unable to add a comment therefor I'm placing it here. As Dexter rightfully asked which browser are you using and if you have Adobe flash installed. I think he forgot to ask what system you are using. I have had customers that had the same problem however they had this problem only in combination with a Mac and Firefox browser.

A quick solution for you could be using Chrome as a browser which should work right outof the box.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and it was solved with browser changem, but now suddenly I can select upload and pick image, but nothing happends. No matter wich brower I use and changed image names, cleaned cache ect. uploaded new adobe flash..(?) So I think this has to deal with related flash auto update.

Answer (score 0):

I also started having this issue in Safari recently. Might have been after a Flash update.

Turn off any adblock, try again.

I works for me in firefox with adblock disabled.